# Missing "jump to member" dropdown in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: Left: VS2013 Right:VS2015]

I am missing this little drop-down from the code editor that lets you jump to the definition of classes (and members) within the opened file.

Don't know what it's called so I have not found a way to enable it. Can't imagine it's missing from 2015.

Comment: I got it back by importing my old settings - still interested in what it's called and how it can be toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called **Navigation bar** and can be enabled separately for different languages in Visual Studio **Text Editor** options:

[image]