# "Toolbar" allowing selection of classes and methods in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I normally have a set of drop-down menus at the top of my code editors that allow me to navigate to a selected class or method within it (etc). Something happened and its gone.

I've tried turning on and off practically everything in the View menu, and also looked at dozens of images of VS in Google Images and can't find a single reference to this thing, whatever it's called.

Does anyone know the name of this widget?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504806/missing-jump-to-member-dropdown-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Wow, well hidden, no?